# Issues with discord bot | charmap' codec can't encode character

Tags: python, windows, bots, discord

i'm trying to make a discord bot with python, my problem is, i want some emojis in the channels names, and when i added the emojis the commands stopped working!

Windows 7
Python 3.7.2

Code:

```py
    channel = client.get_channel(569684483985375242)

    if channel is not None:
        embed=discord.Embed(title="Reage com :white_check_mark: para vermos que não és um bot!", color=0xffff00)
        embed.set_author(name="Verifica-te", icon_url="https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/495260177457741826/569559242382639135/LEIGUINHOS.png?width=644&height=644")
        await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Error:

```py
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2714' in position 29: character maps to <undefined>
```

Tried to fix with:
Code:

```py
    channel1 = client.get_channel(569684483985375242)
    channel = channel1.encode('cp850','replace').decode('cp850')
    if channel is not None:
        embed=discord.Embed(title="Reage com :white_check_mark: para vermos que não és um bot!", color=0xffff00)
        embed.set_author(name="Verifica-te", icon_url="https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/495260177457741826/569559242382639135/LEIGUINHOS.png?width=644&height=644")
        await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Error:

```py
AttributeError: 'TextChannel' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

And then i changed the line:

```py
   channel1 = client.get_channel(569684483985375242)
```

to

```py
   channel1 = str(client.get_channel(569684483985375242))
```

And it gave a error:

```py
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'send'
```

Can someone explain why is it happening and how can i fix it? Thank you, Sorry for my english errors!